# Mybatis:limit offset,length not like in mysql-client

Tags: mysql, mybatis

I am writing a mapper.xml to select data from mysql.
I use `select * from testtable limit #(from),#(number)` to make pages from data.
When I run this sql in mysql-client in shell, from is 0 and number is 100, or from is 100 and number is 100, I can get data. But I can get data when from is 0 and number is 100, can not get any data when from is 100 and number is 100.
what happened, please help me,thanks!!

Comment: How many total # of records are there in testtable?

Comment: @lan Lim there are 10000 records.